# Using \includestandalone for TikZ figure which uses \includegraphics

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone, includegraphics

I have a main document which imports a TikZ figure contained in a standalone document. The TikZ figure uses `\includegraphics` inside one of the nodes, to add a PNG figure in the same folder. It compiles properly by itself, but if I have not pre-compiled it and then try to compile the main document, the PNG image is not included and the node appears empty.

Here is the file structure of the MWE:

```
|- main.tex
|- images
   |- standalone-image.tex
   |- image.png
```

**main.tex**

```
% !TeX document-id = {e9c1e577-28e1-405c-8571-6a9245078427}
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[-shell-escape]
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[mode=buildnew,subpreambles=true]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \includestandalone[width=\linewidth]{images/standalone-image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**standalone-image.tex**

```
\documentclass[tikz,beamer,preview]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{standaloneframe}[fragile]
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node (n) {\includegraphics{image}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{standaloneframe}
\end{document}
```

Any idea how I can get it to compile properly in both cases? I have already played around with the import package and the `\ifstandalone` macro, with no success. Note that the `-shell-escape` flag is included using TeXstudio's "magic comments", so that cannot be the problem either.

Answer (score 3):

You could make tex look into the `images` folder to automatically find the image by using 
`\graphicspath{{images}}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[mode=buildnew,subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\graphicspath{{images}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \includestandalone[width=\linewidth]{images/standalone-image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

To successfully compile your Tikz picture while compiling your main.tex file, you will need to put

```
\node (n) {\includegraphics{images/image}};
```

instead of

```
\node (n) {\includegraphics{image}};
```

which is the correct path of your image relatively to your main.tex file.

Using a Makefile would be a great solution to ensure that the standalone document is well compiled.

Here is an example of a Makefile that could work for you (I did not execute it).

```
 INPUT_DIR      := .
 INPUT          := $(INPUT_DIR)main.tex
 FIGURE_DIR     := $(INPUT_DIR)images/
 TARGET_DIR     := .
 TARGET         := $(TARGET_DIR)main.pdf

 all: figure $(TARGET)

 $(TARGET): $(INPUT_DIR)*.tex $(FIGURE_DIR)
    rubber -m pdftex --into $(TARGET_DIR) $(INPUT)

 figure:
    for file in $$(ls $(FIGURE_DIR)*.tex | cut -d \. -f 1); do \
        make -s $$file.pdf; \
    done;

%.pdf: %.tex
    rubber -m pdftex --inplace $<

.SILENT: figure $(TARGET)
```

(in that particular case, because rubber option --inplace change your location, you won't need to change your image path).

Comment: The first solution is not ideal because it goes against standalone's purpose of making the file compile both by itself or as part of a document seamlessly. About the second, it is not what I was looking for, since it means that I will have to change the way I compile the files. It is annoying for the people I cooperate with if they cannot simply open the document and build normally, and that has been problematic in the past. I was looking for a solution which uses some "pure LaTeX" macros or packages and requires no special ways of compiling, no matter the case.