# Using headers in external TikZ figures with \includestandalone

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, standalone, preamble

I am facing an issue using figures in standalone files. My problem is related to the one described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437913/using-includestandalone-for-tikz-figure-which-uses-includegraphics). As I use many similar styled figures I want to put the header into a separate file so I can reuse it. I would like to have a solution for which I either build the figure separately (in a standalone file) or compile it while compiling the main document. I am using the following file structure and files for my MWE:

```
|- main.tex
|- figureFolder
   |- figure.tex
|- headerFolder
   |- header.tex
```

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%
    subpreambles=true,
    sort=true,
    print=true,
    mode=buildnew]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    Some text
    \begin{figure}
        \includestandalone{figureFolder/figure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**figure.tex**

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\input{../headerFolder/header.tex} % for standalone compilation

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [blue] (0,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**header.tex**

```
\usepackage{tikz}
```

I was thinking abdout adding something like

```
if mainFileCompilation
    \input{headerFolder/header.tex}
else
    \input{../headerFolder/header.tex}
```

to the preamble of the standalone file but I could not figure out how.

Comment: A symbolic link named `header.tex` next to `figure.tex` could do the trick. Otherwise, you could pass a command line argument to the compilation command, or discriminate based on `\jobname`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple solution by adding

```
\IfStandalone{%
    \input{../headerFolder/header.tex}}{%  % for standalone compilation
        \input{headerFolder/header.tex}}
```

to the preamble of figure.tex.